# Getting random exception on running media file through cli mode

Tags: install4j

I am getting random exception on running media file through cli mode using -c and it is happening if i am building media file on my local windows machine and if same media file is built by team member on his local machine with same project files and if that media file is executed without any exception.

Is any configuration or files/JAR are missing from my local machine.
Both machines are windows 10 based and VM is CentOS 7.5 on which media files are executed.

```
An error occurred:
java.lang.NullPointerException
Error log: /opt/install4jError7230162955301840179.log
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.install4j.runtime.util.KeyboardUtil.addAccelerator(KeyboardUtil.java:40)
        at com.install4j.runtime.util.KeyboardUtil.addAccelerator(KeyboardUtil.java:19)
        at com.install4j.runtime.beans.styles.StandardControlButtonComponent.formActivated(StandardControlButtonComponent.java:132)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.activated(FormPanel.java:133)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.handleConsole(FormPanel.java:166)
        at com.install4j.runtime.beans.formcomponents.FormEnvironmentImpl.handleConsole(FormEnvironmentImpl.java:245)
        at com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen.handleConsole(FormScreen.java:166)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.handleScreen(ConsoleScreenExecutor.java:53)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.execute(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:96)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller$1.run(Controller.java:165)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:704)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Finishing installation...
```

Comment: Thanks for your report. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is fixed.

Comment: Please check i have mailed support.

Comment: Thanks Ingo Issue Resolved with latest build